# svn or git for storing image files?

Tags: image, git, svn

I'd like to use svn/git for image backup purposes.
image comprises of jpg/psd/other image-related binary files.

This is primarily for back up purpose. I don't need to keep track of old versions.
repositories makes 'deletion' hard. that's why I'm considering them for back up purpose

Wonder whether svn/git is preferred for this?

(Should this question go to superuser?)

Answer (score 2):

Repositories don't necessarily make deletion hard.  All it takes is `rm -rf *` or a similar command using any other OS or GUI, and your files are gone.

If you don't need version control, why not copy them to removable storage?  External disks are cheap, and many other media are both cheap and rewrite-proof.

Comment: thanks for input. I say it's hard to delete because I can only use svn from a client side(functionality exposed via subversion only), and don't touch the server computer. Whereas, external disks are just too exposed(shown as folder).

Answer (score 1):

Well, personally I prefer GIT over SVN any day. I don't think specifics like "images" should be what defines which you use, so much as what you prefer as a version control system. GIT seems to be all the rage right now, so why not go with that? It also has some great GUIs if that's what you prefer, while SVN GUIs seem to be somewhat lacking.

Answer (score 1):

I have read many posts that for larger repositories GIT was substantially faster.
(I Just don't know if it was size or number of files that was defined by "larger" repos)
Also most new software seems to be on GIT so there must be something about it that draws lots of people to it. Therefore, I would go for GIT :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a version control system solely for storing binary files is generally a bad idea.

I am also not sure if i got your intention right:
Still, if you want to use the VCS to store 'session states' of you working on the pictures, and the undo function of Photoshop is not good enough or if you do not want to store the pictures manually under a different name...

**git is the weapon of choice, since it can be used locally.**

Image files tend to be bigger, so network transfers are getting slow over time, plus git is by itself working faster than svn. (Sure, svn can be set up locally, too, but it's way more hazzle.)
You can work with with remote repositories when using git, if you want. But unlike SVN you can also use git when lacking a network connection.

The availability of graphical front-ends should not be decision maker, since for both systems great tools exist.